# How to uninstall Adobe Creative Cloud - CEF Helper?

Tags: adobe-creative-cloud, adobe-creative-suite

My friend reviews a lot of contracts so she always has Adobe Creative Cloud open on Windows for editing PDFs.

This **Adobe CEF Helper** appears to be for rendering advanced 3D assets or something. It uses multiple processes with Very High power consumption so the fan runs loud 24/7. It has its own task in the Task Manager.

Tried:

- Killing the task, but it just respawns.
- Looked to uninstall it in Creative Cloud Desktop App > Apps. But it is not listed as its own app.
- Tried right-click delete the application file under Adobe Common > HEX. But it did not delete the file.

Comment: You can try uninstalling Creative Cloud and just use Acrobat Pro for editing PDFs.   That is what I do. Creative Cloud is an immense amount of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You might suggest to your friend that they use Adobe Acrobat Pro instead of Creative Cloud.

That is a change but should be better for your friend because Creative Cloud is resource intensive.

Two things:

**(A)** Going to Adobe to install Acrobat Pro installs Creative Cloud by default - no way around this that I know of.

Once the install is done, you can uninstall Creative Cloud and that will just leave Adobe Acrobat Pro (or what your license allows). I have done this to have just Adobe Acrobat Pro.

**(B)** Adobe Acrobat has (recently) changed to a 64-bit version. That works much better on a 64-bit operating system than Adobe 32-bit, including smoother, less resource-intensive operation.

Uninstall Adobe completely (Acrobat, Creative Cloud, Adobe Genuine) and restart the computer.

Install Acrobat again (and then uninstall Creative Cloud) and you should have Adobe Acrobat 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

`Adobe CEF Helper.exe` can cause high CPU or Memory usage issues.
The usual reason is that Adobe Creative Cloud is not installed properly.
You could try to reinstall or repair the installation.

To disable the CEF Helper from running at startup automatically,
this procedure might still work:

- Open Adobe Creative Cloud Desktop
- Click on your Profile Picture
- Click on Preferences
- Under General, toggle "Launch Creative Cloud at login" to Off
- Click Done
- Reboot.